# Find the limit of some roots raised to n

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials

let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the roots of $x^3-x^2-1=0$. If $x_1$ is a real root of the equation, compute: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_2^n+x_3^n).$

First I find these relations using viete:

$x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$

$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=4$

Now, we can find a recurrence of the other sum of roots using the inial equation and we get this sequence:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$$

where

$$a_1=1, a_2=1, a_3=4$$

And I tried something like this to try and solve this problem but couldn't work it out until the end... I'm actually stuck here.

Comment: First point to note is that $x_2$ and $x_3$ are complex conjugates

Comment: @junkquill true.

Comment: @junkquill so If I were to write them with trig form use moivre then I would get rid of $isin(n\phi)$ and get their module raised to n times $cos(n\phi)$

Comment: Yes, Gabriel Romon's answer essentially finishes your thought

Comment: @junkquill but, however could I do it the way I tried at the begininng? using sequences?

Comment: The presence of $x_1$ makes this method a bit complicated, but let me get back to you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard calculus proves that $x^3-x^2-1$ has a single real root $x_1$, and $x_1>1$. It is also standard that the polynomial has two other roots $x_2$ and $x_3$ which are complex conjugates: $x_2=\overline{x_3}$, thus $|x_2|=|x_3|$.

By Vieta, $x_1x_2x_3=1$, thus $|x_2|^2=|x_2x_3|=\frac{1}{|x_1|}<1$, hence $|x_2|<1$.

Let $x_2 = re^{i\theta}$ and note that $x_2^n+x_3^n = r^n 2\cos(n\theta)$

But $r=|x_2|<1$, thus $\lim_n r^n 2\cos(n\theta) = 0$.

Hence $\lim_n x_2^n+x_3^n = 0$.